# onSaveInstanceState not running

Tags: android

I've got a simple orderride on my onSaveInstanceState()

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d("FUApp", "savingInstanceState");
    if (haveLocation) {
        outState.putParcelable("theLocation", theLocation);
        Log.d("FUApp", "Location stored");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("FUApp", "Location wasn't stored");
    }
}
```

and then I have this method for startingActivities

```
public void setupStartActivityIntent(Context base, Class clss, Bundle mBundle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(base, clss);
    if (mBundle != null) {
        intent.putExtras(mBundle);
    }
    if (currentAPIVersion >= 16) {
        Bundle translateBundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(
                base,
                R.anim.slide_in_left,
                R.anim.slide_out_left
        ).toBundle();
        startActivity(intent, translateBundle);
    } else {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Should onSaveInstanceState get ran before the new Activity starts? I'm trying to minimize the number of location request my app is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only called when the application is killed. In this case if you kill the new activity or go back to the previous the Activity will just be resumed and not restarted. The method signiature for [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) explains when it is called.

Comment: Ahh I see. I've started using get last known location now rather than passing the location in the bundle, but it's good to know why it wasn't working.